# Different screen sizes? (landscape)

Tags: java, 2d, android, game-design, textures

**I want to make a separate landscape layout for each size of my original layout**

I have `activity_main.xml`. I have adapted it to be able to fit multiple screen sizes:

[image]

Now, I want to create a landscape layout **for each different screen size**. The android docs and many (Many!) stack overflow pages suggest to do something like this to create a new landscape layout:

[image]

But after doing this, I create a landscape layout for **all of the activity_main.xml's** I need a separate landscape for the large `activity_main`, the small `activity_main`, the xlarge `activity_main`, and the normal `activity_main`. By doing the method described everywhere, I end up with this:

[image]

And because this covers all of the `activity_main.xml`'s, I don't get the option to 'Create Landscape Variation`on my other versions of my`activity_main`.

So, how do I get separate landscape layouts for **each** already made variation of `activity_main`?

Thanks so much,

Ruchir

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of choosing 'Create Landscape Variation', try 'Create Other...' instead. Then you can make a new layout for whatever set of constraints you want. If you want a layout for xlarge screen and landscape. Then just choose size and orientation as your qualifiers and set them correctly to xlarge and landscape. This should create a new folder with a layout for you.

For more detailed explanation on how to create these folders in Android Studio, try looking at this answer. https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/a/112232/75055

Lastly, ask yourself this. Do you really need a separate layout for each possible screen size? Most apps would be fine with 1-2, one for phone sized screens and maybe one for xlarge/tablet sized screens.

Comment: Hey Christer, I have a question similar to this. I'm sure you know the answer, do you mind looking at it? http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/113329/landscape-mode-for-game