# Landscape mode for game?

Tags: java, 2d, android, graphics

### TL;DR: I have made 8 new layouts for each activity layout, but they are not showing up. For example, I have a `layout-land` directory with a layout, but that layout doesn't show up when I turn my phone to landscape?

I have made 8 new layouts for each layout in order to work for every screen size. This took me about 4 hours, but I finally got it done. When I tested it on my phone, and changed to landscape mode, the landscape layout didn't show!

[image]

Why is this? Is it a problem with my directory names? Here is the project view:

[image]

Why isn't the appropriate layout showing? Have I done something wrong and wasted my last 4+ hours by making layouts for each? If you need any more information, feel free to ask for it.

Comment: Do you have `configChanges="orientation"` set in your manifest?

Comment: Are screen rotation locked on your phone? What phone screen size does your phone have, normal, large? Have you tried rotating all the different activities or just one?

Comment: @Christer My phone is normal screen size. Rotation is not locked. I have tried this on all activities.

Comment: @bornander No, I do not. Where should I place that?

Comment: @Christer :) I know, I think you read my comment wrong, I said it is **not** locked. If it were locked, then I wouldn't have come to know of this issue. :-)

Comment: @RuchirBaronia Does it work in the emulator? You press left-ctrl+F12 to change orientation.

Comment: @Christer It does, but I don't have many virtual devices to test it on, as my  `genymotion` is giving me some errors. It works on the phones that I have tested it on though. :)

Comment: @Christer Why not my real life phone though?

Comment: @RuchirBaronia Maybe you are just confusing the screen lock. I actually just made that mistake on my phone where the button enables and disables screen rotation rather than locking it. So it's like opposite. If that doesn't help I have really no idea what it could be. Does the screen rotation work on other apps?

Comment: @Christer Oh no! Thats not what I'm saying. The screen rotation works fine. It's just that when I rotate the screen, my `land` directories layout is not getting created, and so all of the views just overlap each other. Why is that? I need to display the landscape view whenever the phone gets rotated, the XLarge view whenever there is an XLarge phone, the Small view whenever there is a small phone, etc. What can I do? thanks so much

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/33234/discussion-between-christer-and-ruchir-baronia).

Comment: @Christer I'm sorry, there were so many problems with my wifi. I have stable wifi connection now, and am in the chat now

Comment: @Christer Also, I have read (http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/providing-resources.html#BestMatch)[this] and I didn't find anything that says `layout-normal` overrides `layout-landscape`.

Comment: @RuchirBarona Under "How Android Finds the Best-matching Resource" it says that it finds the qualifiers in the order found on the list. Then if one matches, all the ones without that qualifier is discarded. Screen-size is before orientation, so if it finds a qualifier that matches screen-size, then all folders without a screen-size are ignored.

Comment: @Christer I have posted a question on it. I still didn't see the part where it finds the qualifiers in the order of the list, feel free to post the list. I have asked another question:http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/114355/different-layouts