# My game has messed up layouts!

Tags: java, 2d, android, game-design, software-engineering

Earlier, I asked this question:
[Landscape mode for game?](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/113329/landscape-mode-for-game)

Where I had a directory for each and every layout, but the layout in the `layout-land` directory wasn't showing up when positioning my layout in landscape orientation. [image]

So, someone suggested to me that it maybe that the

- `Layout-normal` directories are overriding my regular `layout-land` directories. Is this true?
- If so, will any other of my layout folders get overriding?** What is the purpose of `layout-normal` in the first place then anyway?

Answer (score 1):

Look at this flow chart from Google that shows how the resource folder is picked.

[Android qualifier flow chart](http://developer.android.com/images/resources/res-selection-flowchart.png)

Screen-size comes before orientation. So when you have a folder with screen-size that matches your device, all of the folders without it will be discarded. Since layout-land doesn't have screen-size it will be ignored.

For a list of the qualifiers look at this link. Please look at table 2.
[Table over Andriod qualifiers](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/providing-resources.html#AlternativeResources)