# Different layouts?

Tags: java, 2d, android, optimization

I have had trouble in the past with optimizing my game for different layouts, so that the players don't see the game in different ways on different screens. Someone told me that the `normal` directory would override the `large-land` directory, and oddly enough it was true, so I deleted the `normal` directory.

[image]

**Will any other layouts override each other?** I have put every layout into each of these folders, and edited appropriately (took me a week of many hours!), so every directory you see in the picture, has multiple XML resource folders within. Do I need to do anything else to optimize my app for all layouts? I have added the following in my manifest:

```
<supports-screens
        android:anyDensity="true"
        android:largeScreens="true"
        android:normalScreens="true"
        android:smallScreens="true"
        android:xlargeScreens="true" />
```

Thanks,

Ruchir

Comment: http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/33234/discussion-between-christer-and-ruchir-baronia

Comment: @Christer What does step 2 in the table mean? What is mcc? Thanks Christer!

Comment: I don't know what mcc means, however it is the first qualifier in this table developer.android.com/guide/… which is sorted after importance, most important first. This is the table refered to by step 2 in the flow-chart I showed you.

Comment: @Christer Then how do you know that `layout-normal` is mcc?

Comment: @RuchirBarcona Never said it was. If it had the mcc-qualifier it would look more like this ´layout-mcc310-normal´. Btw the screen-size is row number 7. It is there the ´normal´ qualifier is.